# PHP File that contains Scripts and Resources from Head Tag (Problem with PHP include)

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to create a PHP file that will contain `scripts`, `css` links and resources just like I have `header.php` and `footer.php`. However, when I create that file and include it in my `<head>` it does not apply to the page in question.

I have tried including it in `<head>` tags and `<body>` tags above the PHP include `header.php` but still no results. I tried different formats as well.

```
<?php include 'includes/scripts.php'; ?>
<?php include ('includes/scripts.php'); ?>
```

I want to inlcude files such as:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

[header location for the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnPzA.png)

[index code location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oeSV.png)

[scripts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYRZx.png)

Comment: what error are you getting? If the file is not being included it should be warning you.

Comment: Have you changed the default `includes path` by calling `set_include_path` anywhere? If not then your directory `includes` is unknown most likely

Comment: I didn't use set_include_path, doI have to use that? as php include works fine for header.php file

Comment: @XOGamingGB what is the error or warning are you getting on the page?

Comment: I don't see any errors as I am only using XAMPP and notepad++

Comment: @XOGamingGB post a screenshot of your HTML `header` section where you include the `scripts.php`.

Comment: have you tried clearing cache ?

Comment: just uploaded the images above, indeed I tried and still the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `header.php` file, and `script.php` file remove the `<HTML>`, `<HEAD>`, `<BODY>` tags, and also remove the `<meta charset="utf-8">`. In both of the files, keep only what you want to include into your `index.php` file.

You do not need to include the `script.php` file in the `header.php` file, instead include it only in the `index.php` file.

So you can keep only these things in your `script.php` file:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

Also in your `header.php` file you can keep only the contents which is wrapped with the `<nav>` element, and finally include the both files in your `index.php` file as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <?php require('includes/script.php');?>
 </head>
<body>
 <?php require('includes/header.php');?>
 // your rest of your elements here
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks I managed to sort it out, im not sure what happened there thanks for your help as without it I would still be on it :)

Comment: @XOGamingGB I am glad, my answer helped you out.